# Railo cannot add event gateway under service in web admin

Tags: web-config, settings, railo, admin-rights, event-gateway

I am working on a railo 4.2.1.008 server. I can run the web admin from localhost/railo-context/admin/web.cfm and www.mydomain.com/railo-context/admin/web.cfm. Both of them are showing individual settings. But the local one allows me to add an event gateway. When I added one, it lists the added instance above the add form. But in the other one, the form get submits and it is not listing anything. i am not sure it is added or not. Also I am not sure both the admin console are running from a same folder. Can anyone advice me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue.Please check your application.cfc and check for any onrequest codes.In my case I renamed my application.cfc and it worked as the application.cfc variables got reset.

Comment: Thank a lot. My issue got vanished once I have changed my application name. Don't know why it is not working when I have restarted my railo service.